# Unexpected '++' in jslint 

Tags: javascript, jslint

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why avoid increment (“++”) and decrement (“--”) operators in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971312/why-avoid-increment-and-decrement-operators-in-javascript)
>   [The “unexpected ++” error in jslint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000276/the-unexpected-error-in-jslint)

jslint.com is giving me the error:

```
Unexpected '++'.
```

for this line:

```
for (i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
```

I tried `i++` but no go.

Comment: Try i+=1?      .........

Comment: There must be more to this than what you've shown..

Comment: Because of rules like this, I use http://www.jshint.com/ try it out

Comment: First line says `jshint`, but question title says `jslint`, which are you using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971312/why-avoid-increment-and-decrement-operators-in-javascript

Answer (score 12):

JSLint does not like the increment and decrement operators. Replace it with `i += 1` or add the `plusplus: true` directive to the top of your file (if you're not sure how to set JSLint directives, here's an example. They are set in a normal comment at the top of your file):

```
/*jslint plusplus: true */
```

From the [JSLint docs](http://www.jslint.com/help.html):

> The `++` (increment) and `--` (decrement) operators have been known to
>   contribute to bad code by encouraging excessive trickiness. They are
>   second only to faulty architecture in enabling to viruses and other
>   security menaces.

Completely ridiculous rule? You can make your own mind up...

Comment: Wow, jslint... you have disappointed me

Comment: this is bad English..... faulty architecture in enabling to viruses

Comment: Yea, I agree.  This is crap.  `i++;` has been used since the beginning of time..

Comment: Since even before computers, cavemen engraved it inside their graves

Comment: @MikeChristensen, `i++` has been *abused* since programmers started learning they could squish more into one line than was reasonable. The whole point of linting is to make code more expressive. If you know the algorithm is sound and it uses `++`, then ignore the warning. It **is** just a warning.

Comment: Crockford can be a bit...*strict* in his recommendations. This is one of those guidelines I just don't understand.

Comment: It's because of confusing errors like this that I am gradually building up a comprehensive set of explanations of JSLint errors. Unfortunately this one isn't on there yet. It's all on GitHub, so if anyone feels like adding stuff in, have a look: http://jslinterrors.com/

Answer (score -3):

Try:
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {

If that doesn't work, see if i is defined by typing i in console and seeing the response.