# Tolerate ++ operator in JSLint plugin for Sublime Text

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3, jslint, sublime-jslint

I use the [`JSLint`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/JSLint) plugin for ST (in addition to the `Sublime​Linter-jshint` plugin).

I disagree with the theory that the use of `++` or `--` is evil, tricky etc. and use them quite freely. As such I don't appreciate the warning that I should use `+= 1` instead of `++` throughout my code.

I have tried adding the line `/*jslint plusplus: true */` at the beginning of my code as per [Unexpected '++' in jslint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996293/unexpected-in-jslint) 
but this did not help.

How can I make a global setting for the JSLint ST plugin to tolerate the usage of `++` and `--`?

Comment: JSLint is pretty opinionated. If you're looking to configure rules, you might like [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) or [ESLint](http://eslint.org/) better.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I shall give them a go. I had a quick look into them and they do appear more promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched through the [`JSLint`](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint) repo on Github, and couldn't find any mention of a `plusplus` option in the current version of [`jslint.js`](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/master/jslint.js). So, I did some digging, and found that the `plusplus` option was removed in [this commit](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/557afd32bcaa35480d31a86f02d3a8c06a4e5b5c/jslint.js) on May 1, 2015 (it was still present in [the previous commit](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/394bf291bfa3881bb9827b9fc7b7d1112d83f313/jslint.js#L197)). [Here](https://plus.google.com/+DouglasCrockfordEsq/posts/aBLU9y4Fd4z) is Crockford's announcement that he'll be removing that option, among others, in his next release.

Therefore, because this option was removed about a year ago, you just won't be able to use it with current versions of JSLint.

Comment: A bit of a disappointing answer, but that's not your fault and it looks correct. I might look into @saadq suggestions above.  Thanks