# Unexpected '=' error in JSLint

Tags: javascript, jslint

I used JSLint on a zepto extension js file

It threw the error:

```
Unexpected '='. line 33 character 37
```

line 33:

```
return (document.cookie = [encodeURIComponent(key), '=', options.raw ? value : encodeURIComponent(value), options.expires ? '; expires=' + options.expires.toUTCString() : '', options.path ? '; path=' + options.path : '', options.domain ? '; domain=' + options.domain : '', options.secure ? '; secure' : ''].join(''));
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split it to 2 statements:

```
document.cookie = [encodeURIComponent(key), '=', options.raw ? value : encodeURIComponent(value), options.expires ? '; expires=' + options.expires.toUTCString() : '', options.path ? '; path=' + options.path : '', options.domain ? '; domain=' + options.domain : '', options.secure ? '; secure' : ''].join('');
return document.cookie;
```

generally you don't use assignment in a `return` expression.

Comment: @zerkms.. Why would that be a problem.. ??  The value is first assigned and then returned right

Comment: @Sushanth --: a problem from what perspective? JSLint hints you about *potential problems* and *bad practices*. In this case it may be either: problem of confusing `=` and `==`, or just mis-using assignment

Comment: I know that's a bad practice but was wondering if this is just in perspective of JSLint .. Cause in general the correct value will be return by the function right

Comment: @Sushanth --: Well, JSLint has even more strange checks like: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3000276/251311 But in this case I'm 100% agree with JSLint, I think it's just an example of bad coding practice