# What does JSLint mean by 'Unexpected expression 'i' in statement position.'?

Tags: javascript, jslint

I have a for loop in JavaScript that I have run through JSLint a few times.  In the past I received `the unexpected++ error`, I decided to refactor to make my code more readable.  A month or so later JSLint came out with an update and is now showing the warning...

> Unexpected expression 'i' in statement position. 
>   for (i; i < scope.formData.tabs.length; i = i + 1) {

```
//See JSLint.com for why I pulled out i initialization and i = i+1 instead of i++
//and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000276/the-unexpected-error-in-jslint
var i = 0;
for (i; i < scope.formData.tabs.length; i += 1) {
    scope.formData.tabs[i].show = false; // hide all the other tabs 

    if (scope.formData.tabs[i].title === title) {
        scope.formData.tabs[i].show = true; // show the new tab 
    }
}
```

Reverting to `var i = 0` and `i++` does not get improve the warnings, JSLint just stops processing.

Comment: There's no reason to have that `i` there in the first part of the for loop, if you do the declaration & initialization elsewhere then just leave that part blank and keep the semicolon-

Comment: Removing that causing warnings directly in Visual Studio and shows as `Unexpected 'for'.` and `Expected ';' and instead saw ')'.` in JSLint.  I am pretty sure the for needs all three components to work correctly.

Comment: Visual Studio is a terrible IDE in my persional opinion. `for(;i<x;i++) statement;` is a perfectly valid for loop, no matter what it tells you.

Comment: I did not have the `;` in front, but with that in, both old.jslint.com and jslint.com report the following when the `;` is in.  `Expected ';' and instead saw 'i'.
     for (;i < scope.formData.tabs.length; i = i + 1) {
line 18 character 14Expected ')' and instead saw '<'.
     for (;i < scope.formData.tabs.length; i = i + 1) {`

Comment: If you still don't believe me, see the [MDN docs for the `for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for#Optional_for_expressions)

Comment: Where did you see that `var i=0; for (i; ...` is preferred over `var i; for (i=0; ...` in JSLint? I didn't necessarily see that in the [linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000276/the-unexpected-error-in-jslint), nor at the JSLint instructions.

Comment: @ruffin I made that comment in my code probably around a year ago, I am not sure where I saw that.  I do not see it in the code for the other question or in the JSLint instructions either, but since they have upgraded their site it is possible that changed.  It may have been an old message that JSLint gave related to [declaring multiple variables together](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/694102/declaring-multiple-variables-in-javascript), I know that I refactored due to that often.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like [the follow-up problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30265001/what-does-jslint-mean-by-unexpected-expression-i-in-statement-position#comment48630254_30265001) isn't [just?] due to JSLint being in beta. **It's because Crockford no longer allows `for` statements by default.** Looks like I'm going to need to set aside a weekend to [read the new instructions](http://jslint.com/help.html) and [source](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/master/jslint.js). Strange things are afoot at the Circle K, man.

> The most important new feature of ES6 is proper tail calls. This has
>   no new syntax, so JSLint doesn't see it. But it makes recursion much more
>   attractive, which makes loops, particularly for loops, much less
>   attractive.

Then this in the `/*jslint */` directive section's main table:

> Description: Tolerate `for` statement
>   Option: `for`
>   Meaning: `true` if the `for` statement should be allowed.

There's a little more explanation below the table:

> JSLint does not recommend use of the `for` statement. Use array methods
>   like `forEach` instead. The `for` option will suppress some warnings. The
>   forms of `for` that JSLint accepts are restricted, excluding the new ES6 forms.

So to make this lint in the new JSLint, you need at *least* this code (with the `for` directive set):

```
/*jslint white:true, for:true */
/*global scope, title */

function test()
{
    "use strict";
    var i;

    for (i=0; i < scope.formData.tabs.length; i = i + 1) {
        scope.formData.tabs[i].show = false; // hide all the other tabs 

        if (scope.formData.tabs[i].title === title) {
            scope.formData.tabs[i].show = true; // show the new tab 
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I *did* still have to move `i`'s initialization, so you might still have an issue worth [reporting](https://plus.google.com/communities/104441363299760713736). I'll also admit [I'm with Stephen at the question you link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000276/the-unexpected-error-in-jslint#comment4385119_3000276); I'm not sure why `i+= 1` is better. But now it looks like a hard requirement. No `plusplus` option.

Notice also that if the code isn't wrapped in a function (I wrapped in `test`, above), you'll get `Unexpected 'for' at top level.`, which is a new error.

Comment: These questions may be better for the jslint forum or reading the docs, but I thought I would check to see if you happen to know.  I checked Assume ES6, Tolerate 'for statement' and 'messy white space'.  Is there another check that I should do using the interface that will interact better with the 'unexpected expression' message or were you using custom /*jslint ignore*/ tags?

Comment: Just used the code above. I did try adding `es6:true` to the `jslint` directives comment, and it worked fine as well.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** It seems as if I was mistaken. See ruffin's answer for a more detailed explanation.

It seems as if the problem is with jslint.com. Remember, it is still in beta. If you use the old version ([old.jslint.com](http://old.jslint.com/)), the problem seems to go away.

Here's the output for old.jslint.com:
[image]
It's mostly all about scope not being defined... etc.

Here's the output from jslint.com:
[image]
It's about scope not getting defined... etc AND

> Unexpected 'for'.

along with

> Unexpected expression 'i' in statement position.

For now, I suppose you should just use the old version of jslint.com.

Comment: I missed the beta text next to the header.  I will just hold off doing anything with this till I see that go away.  The old jslint site gives me the expected results.

Comment: @JabberwockyDecompiler Good. Glad I could help!

Comment: I am changing the accepted answer to ruffin's he provided a better explanation of what might be going on behind the scenes with this error.  Thank you for helping.