# JSLint: Unexpected 'for'. Unexpected 'var'

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, jslint

I've searching and trying other suggestions in StackOverflow. 
Unfortunately the answers are not working for me. They are suggesting to use 'foreach' instead of 'for', but how could I... if I want to iterate just 50 times? :<

Well, I'll just paste the code and let's see if some good folk can help me.

> [JSLint](http://jslint.com/) was unable to finish.
>
> > Unexpected 'for'.        for (var i=1;i<=50;i+=1){
> >     line 6 column 8
> >
> > Unexpected 'var'.        for (var i=1;i<=50;i+=1){
> >     line 6 column 13

```
    "use strict";

    var campo = [];
    var ronda = 0;

    // Llenamos el campo de 50 humanos/maquinas/extraterrestres = 150 jugadores
    for (var i=1;i<=50;i+=1){
        campo.push(new Human("h"+i));
        campo.push(new Machine("m"+i));
        campo.push(new Alien("e"+i));
    }

    // Array.prototype.suffle para barajar el Array
    Array.prototype.shuffle = function() {
        var input = this;

        for (var i=input.length-1;i>=0;i-=1){
            var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*(i+1));
            var itemAtIndex = input[randomIndex];

            input[randomIndex]=input[i];
            input[i] = itemAtIndex;
        }
    };

    // Barajamos el Array campo
    campo.shuffle();

    // Comprobamos que quedan más de 1 jugador por ronda
    while (campo.length>1) {
        console.log("Iniciando ronda: " + ++ronda);
        console.log(campo.length + " jugadores luchando.");
        // Recorremos el campo, y luchamos

        var muertos = 0;

        for (var i=0; i<campo.length-1; i+=2){
            // Caso de numero impar de jugadores:
            // Por ejemplo cuando solo quedan 3 jugadores. Pelean 1 vs 2. El 3 se libra.
            // - Si siguen vivos y aguantan otra ronda, se barajan las posiciones otra vez y
            //  vuelven a pelear dos. Y el nuevo tercero no pelea.
            // - Si uno de los dos muere, en la siguiente ronda ya solo quedan 2, y pelean normal.

            campo[i].fight(campo[(i+1)]);
            // # descomentar solo la siguiente linea para hacer comprobaciones #
            // console.log("["+ campo[i].username + "] VS ["+ campo[(i+1)].username + "]");
            if (campo[i].health<=0) {
                console.log("El " + campo[i].constructor.name + " llamado " + campo[i].showName() + " ha sido asesinado :<");
                var fallecido = campo.splice(i, 1);

                // # descomentar solo la siguiente linea para hacer comprobaciones #
                //console.log(fallecido[0]);
                i--; // como el array se hace pequeño, hay que corregir el error para que no se salte jugadores
                muertos++;
            } else {
                if (campo[(i+1)].health<=0) {
                    console.log("El " + campo[(i+1)].constructor.name + " llamado " + campo[(i+1)].showName() + " ha sido asesinado :<");
                    var fallecido = campo.splice((i+1), 1);

                    // # descomentar solo la siguiente linea para hacer comprobaciones #
                    // console.log(fallecido[0]);
                    i--; // como el array se hace pequeño, hay que corregir el error para que no se salte jugadores
                    muertos++;
                }
                else {
                    // # descomentar solo la siguiente linea para hacer comprobaciones #
                    // console.log("Siguen vivos");
                }
            }
        }

        console.log("Fin de ronda!")
        if (muertos === 1) {
            console.log("Ha muerto " + muertos + " jugador.");
        } else {
            console.log("Han muerto " + muertos + " jugadores.");
        }

        // Al final de la ronda barajamos de nuevo
        campo.shuffle();
   }

    if (campo.length === 1) {
        console.log("Vaya!! Ha sido una memorable batalla!");
        console.log("Después de tantos bits derramados y de " + ronda + " rondas... el jugador '" + campo[0].constructor.name + "' llamado '" + campo[0].showName() + "' se ha alzado con la victoria!!");
    }
```

There are some other for in the code, but It seems to stop at the first one.
Thank you in advance!
Forgot to say, the code works PERFECT. But I was just validating it with JSLint, also 'tolerating' for warnings in JSLint doesn't work.

Comment: This is just Crockford being stupid, again, telling you `for` loops should never ever be used. I would just ignore it.

Comment: This question indicates there is an option to ignore this warning 'tolerate for'.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518554/jslint-unexpected-for

Comment: Yeah, ignoring it should be the best... but I just want to really learn how to deal with this. I know there are a lot of threads with this "for" problem but no one worked for me. Thank you anyways!

Comment: @miltonb yeah, (I edited it at the bottom) that I've tried to check "Tolerate For Statement" warnings in JSLint but it is still giving me the warning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you choose to tolerate `for`, the next thing it's warning you about is the global declaration of the `var i`. Since you've got the for-loop at the top-level, `i` becomes available everywhere in your program.

I'd just tolerate `for` and wrap it up an in IIFE. That way, `i` is only available inside this function, and doesn't leak out to the global scope.

```
(function() {
    var i = 0;
    for (i=1;i<=50;i+=1) {
        campo.push(new Human("h"+i));
        campo.push(new Machine("m"+i));
        campo.push(new Alien("e"+i));
    }
})();
```

---

You could also, barring using an existing implementation out there, create a function that generalizes the "repeat n times" definition.

```
function repeat(fn, n) {
  var i = 0;
  for (;i < n; i += 1) {
    fn();
  }
}
```

Use in your case would look like:

```
function initialize() { 
    campo.push(new Human("h"+i));
    campo.push(new Machine("m"+i));
    campo.push(new Alien("e"+i));
}

// then later
repeat(initialize, 50);
```

Comment: Awesome, that did the trick. Thank you so much. Is there any other solutions? It makes the code a bit messy :-) I know maybe I am asking too much!

Comment: Well, this function is specialized to your code. There's nothing stopping you from creating a function `repeat()` that takes a function and number of times, and calls the function the given number of times. This is infact what lodash does: https://lodash.com/docs#times

Comment: Also, there's plenty of other folks with JavaScript chops out there that may very well have something more idiomatic or better - that checkmark often discourages more answers. If after a couple (few?) days this remains the best solution for you, then it may be appropriate then.

Comment: Great. I will check this library and again, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Or you can just push *all* your code into a closure and immediately invoke the function, if you wanted. That's a little ugly, but does have the jQuery document ready feel to it, and isn't precisely anti-pattern. I've started wondering if I shouldn't do that by default for precisely the reason jdphenix suggests -- so you guarantee you don't pollute global scope.

Answer (score 5):

jslint is being overzealous (some would say), it expects all `var` statements to be at the top of a function.

You can tell jslint that you don't care about that rule by adding an instruction comment on the line above where you are declaring the variable.

```
// Llenamos el campo de 50 humanos/maquinas/extraterrestres = 150 jugadores
/*jslint for:true */
for (var i=1;i<=50;i+=1){
```

Or you can move all your `var i;` to the top of the file/function

Comment: I put that code in the first line but didn't do anything. So I tried this other solution, I moved the for (var=i.... and declared var=i; at the top. But now it's saying: Unexpected 'for' at top level.
        for (i=1;i<=50;i+=1){

Comment: @JoseSerodio Not in the first line, you add that comment right above the for loop